# "Are a", plural / singular irony

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I read on news that

> ... such checks are a must for ...

why is the plural subject here followed by "a", a singular determiner?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Look up the meanings for *must* in a good dictionary. Let us know if you still have any questions. Good Luck.

Comment: *People are **a** mystery.* Nothing says both halves of a copula must be the same number. That one wasn't.

Comment: Consider: ***a** dozen eggs*.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: because *a must* is a fixed idiom.

But we could replace it with *a requirement*, if the checks are considered collectively: what is required is not each check separately, but the practice of making such checks.

We say “these people are a family” without worrying about the number.